# Why GSON fails to convert Object when it's a field of another Object?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson

GSON fails to convert `Errorneous` to JSON properly when it's inside of other `Object`.

But it works well when it's converted as a top level object. Why, and how to fix it?

Example:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder

sealed class Errorneous<R> {}
data class Success<R>(val result: R) : Errorneous<R>()
data class Fail<R>(val error: String) : Errorneous<R>()

class Container(val value: Errorneous<String>)

fun main() {
  print(GsonBuilder().create().toJson(Container(Fail("some error"))))

  print(GsonBuilder().create().toJson(Fail<String>("some error")))
}
```

Output

```
{"value":{}}

{"error":"some error"}
```

But it should be

```
{"value":{"error":"some error"}}

{"error":"some error"}
```

Comment: This happens because Gson cannot resolve the actual subtype on the given `<R>` that is unknown at runtime for the `Container` class scope. What you can do here is either removing `<R>` from the `Errorneous` class (that makes sense), or try to propagate the `<R>` parameter to the `Container<R>` class and use type token (it doesn't seem to work though; a Gson bug?).

Comment: I guess the reason of the behavior is the way Gson resolves actual types. Registering a type adapter factory can produce the following output when serializing `Container` instances: `Container`, `Errorneous<java.lang.String>` -- it does not resolve the last one as a `Fail<R>` (because field type is not accessible for type adapter factories, hence it merely cannot do `.getClass()` on the value), + plus it _looks like_ `Success<String>` to Gson. The core issue is that Gson does not know which class it should use.

Comment: @Mafor thanks for link, but I don't like the answers from that question, the accepted answer  suggest to use `List<Object>` type instead of specific `List<A>` which is bad, and most popular answer says it's fixed in Gson > v2.1, but I'm using v 2.8 and still have that problem, maybe my case is different.

Comment: @AlexCraft As far as I understand, Gson v2.1 supports polymorphic collections, which is sth a bit different. This answer should work in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15016251/9090751

Comment: @Mafor thanks, yes that one is good enough :)

Comment: @Mafor, update: all works.

Answer (score 1):

I made some comments regarding Gson behavior right under the post (in short: not enough runtime type information), so this is only code to make it work and make it actual type-aware.

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
            @Override
            @Nullable
            public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                final Class<? super T> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
                if ( rawType != Errorneous.class ) {
                    return null;
                }
                final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) typeToken.getType();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final TypeToken<Success<?>> successTypeToken = (TypeToken<Success<?>>) TypeToken.getParameterized(Success.class, parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments());
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final TypeToken<Fail<?>> failTypeToken = (TypeToken<Fail<?>>) TypeToken.getParameterized(Fail.class, parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments());
                final TypeAdapter<Success<?>> successTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, successTypeToken);
                final TypeAdapter<Fail<?>> failTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, failTypeToken);
                final TypeAdapter<Errorneous<?>> concreteTypeAdapter = new TypeAdapter<Errorneous<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Errorneous<?> value)
                            throws IOException {
                        if ( value instanceof Success ) {
                            final Success<?> success = (Success<?>) value;
                            successTypeAdapter.write(out, success);
                            return;
                        }
                        if ( value instanceof Fail ) {
                            final Fail<?> fail = (Fail<?>) value;
                            failTypeAdapter.write(out, fail);
                            return;
                        }
                        throw new AssertionError(); // even null cannot get here: it is protected with .nullSafe() below
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Errorneous<?> read(final JsonReader in) {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }
                };
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = ((TypeAdapter<T>) concreteTypeAdapter)
                        .nullSafe();
                return typeAdapter;
            }
        })
        .create();

@AllArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private abstract static class Errorneous<R> {
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final class Success<R>
        extends Errorneous<R> {

    private final R result;

}

@AllArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final class Fail<R>
        extends Errorneous<R> {

    private final String error;

}

@AllArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static class Container {

    private final Errorneous<String> value;

}

public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(new Container(new Fail<>("some error"))));
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(new Fail<>("some error")));
}
```

As you can see, the type adapter factory first resolves type adapters for both `Success` and `Fail`, and then picks a proper one based on the actual class of the `Errorneous` value with `instanceof` ().

Here is what it prints:

```json
{"value":{"error":"some error"}}
{"error":"some error"}
```

The deserialization is made an unsupported operation since it must decide how the JSON can be deserialized: 1) either on a type designator field (see `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` in Gson extras in their repository on GitHub; it's not bundled and published as an artifact); 2) or analyze the structure of the object making heuristics analysis (much harder to implement and may face with ambiguous cases).

I don't do Kotlin, but the Java code above can be probably easily converted to its Kotlin counterpart right in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and writing the solution code! It's not good that you have to write JSON mapping code manually, but there's probably no better way...

Comment: @AlexCraft Unfortunately, type adapter factories accept only the declaration site type via type tokens, so the actual runtime type should be resolved in other way (e.g. manually). I guess that the Gson authors decided not to include it by default because of several issues, one of which I mentioned above and suppressed with an unsupported operation exception stub (no easy way to deserialize). It's only a guess, as they also mention that non static anonymous classes cannot serialized because of a similar reason (no way to deserialize its inner `this`).

Answer (score 0):

Answer in Kotlin copied from the [similar Java Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153582/gson-doesnt-serialize-fields-defined-in-subclasses/15016251#15016251)

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
import java.lang.reflect.Type

sealed class Errorneous<R> {}
data class Success<R>(val result: R) : Errorneous<R>()
data class Fail<R>(val error: String) : Errorneous<R>()

class Container(
  val value: Errorneous<String>
 )

fun main() {
  val builder = GsonBuilder()
  builder.registerTypeAdapter(
    Errorneous::class.java, ErrorneousSerializer()
  )
  val gson = builder.create()
  print(gson.toJson(Container(Fail("some error"))))
  print(gson.toJson(Fail<String>("some error")))
}

class ErrorneousSerializer : JsonSerializer<Errorneous<Any>> {
  override fun serialize(
    o: Errorneous<Any>, type: Type, ctx: JsonSerializationContext
  ): JsonElement {
    return ctx.serialize(o as Any)
  }
}
```

Comment: It may be a suboptimal solution since it uses in-memory JSON trees rather than JSON token streaming.