# Gson add field during serialization

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I can't find a simple way to add a custom field during serialization in Gson and I was hoping someone else may be able to help.

Here is a sample class to show my issue:

```
public class A {
  String id;
  String name;
  ...
}
```

When I serialize class A I would like to return something like:

```
{ "id":"123", "name":"John Doe", "url_to_user":"http://www.example.com/123" }
```

where url_to_user is not stored in my instance of class A, but can be generated with data in the instance of class A.

Is there a simple way of doing this? I would prefer to avoid writing an entire serializer just to add one field.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `Gson.toJsonTree` to get a `JsonElement`, with which you can interact dynamically.

```
A a = getYourAInstanceHere();
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(a);
jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("url_to_user", url);
return gson.toJson(jsonElement);
```

Comment: Simple... would hope there would be a simpler way, e.g. a method on the object...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the top rated answer is quite a quick one and not essentially *bad* when you are lacking much time but here is the problem: There is no proper [separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

You are modifying the serialized JSON at the same place where you are writing your business logic. You should be doing all the serialization inside of a `TypeAdapter` or a `JsonSerializer`.

**How can we maintain a proper separation of concern?**

The answer wraps around a bit of additional complexity but the architecture demands it. Here we go(taken from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800433/polymorphism-with-gson/)):

First, we would be using a custom serializer for the type. Second, we would have to create a *copy constructor* inside the base class and a wrapper subclass as follows:

*Note: The custom serializer might seem like an overkill but trust me, it pays off in long run for maintainability.*
.

```
// Lets say the base class is named Cat
public class Cat {

    public String name;

    public Cat(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    // COPY CONSTRUCTOR
    public Cat(Cat cat) {
        this.name = cat.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String sound() {
        return name + " : \"meaow\"";
    };
}



    // The wrapper subclass for serialization
public class CatWrapper extends Cat{


    public CatWrapper(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public CatWrapper(Cat cat) {
        super(cat);
    }
}
```

And the serializer for the type `Cat`:

```
public class CatSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Cat> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Cat src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

        // Essentially the same as the type Cat
        JsonElement catWrapped = context.serialize(new CatWrapper(src));

        // Here, we can customize the generated JSON from the wrapper as we want.
        // We can add a field, remove a field, etc.

        // The main logic from the top rated answer now here instead of *spilling* around(Kindly ignore the cat having a url for the sake of example)
        return catWrapped.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("url_to_user", url);
    }
}
```

So, why a copy constructor?

Well, once you define the copy constructor, no matter how much the base class changes, your wrapper will continue with the same role. Secondly, if we don't define a copy constructor and simply subclass the base class then we would have to "talk" in terms of the extended class, i.e, `CatWrapper`. It is quite possible that your components talk in terms of the base class and not the wrapper type.