# Adding an existing json string with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a String object containing some arbitrary json. I want to wrap it inside another json object, like this:

```
{
   version: 1,
   content: >>arbitrary_json_string_object<<
}
```

How can I reliably add my json string as an attribute to it without having to build it manually (ie avoiding tedious string concatenation)?

```
class Wrapper {
   int version = 1;
}

gson.toJson(new Wrapper())
// Then what?
```

Note that the added json should *not* be escaped, but a be part of the wrapper as a valid json entity, like this:

```
{
   version: 1,
   content: ["the content", {name:"from the String"}, "object"]
}
```

given

```
String arbitraryJson = "[\"the content\", {name:\"from the String\"}, \"object\"]";
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `content` String field? I'm curious to see the result.

Comment: Probably the content will be escaped.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Object object = gson.fromJson(arbitraryJson, Object.class);

  Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
  w.content = object;

  System.out.println(gson.toJson(w));
```

where I changed your `Wrapper` class in:

```
// setter and getters omitted
public class Wrapper {
  public int version = 1;
  public Object content;
}
```

You can also write a custom serializer for your `Wrapper` if you want to hide the details of the deserialization/serialization.

Answer (score 19):

For those venturing on this topic, consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025252/391618).

```
A a = getYourAInstanceHere();
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(a);
jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("url_to_user", url);
return gson.toJson(jsonElement);
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer! Also, if you wish to add a custom object make another JsonElement like `JsonElement jsonElement2 = gson.toJsonTree(b);` and add to the existing one, using:                        `jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().add("other", jsonElement2);`

Answer (score 8):

Simple, convert your bean to a `JsonObject` and add a property.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject object = (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(new Wrapper());
object.addProperty("content", "arbitrary_json_string");
System.out.println(object);
```

prints

```
{"version":1,"content":"arbitrary_json_string"}
```

Comment: Does this work if the `"arbitrary_json_string"` is a JSON *object*?

Comment: @LutzHorn You can use `JsonObject#add(JsonElement)` for that.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to deserialize it first, then add it to your structure and re-serialize the whole thing. Otherwise, the wrapper will just contain the wrapped JSON in a fully escaped string.

This is assuming you have the following in a string:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

and want it wrapped in your `Wrapper` object, resulting in a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "content": {"foo": "bar"}
}
```

If you did not deserialize first, it would result in the following:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "content": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
}
```

Comment: No, you won't have to. You can use the intermediary `JsonObject` that uses a `LinkedTreeMap` underneath.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I do not think that does what I think OP is trying to achieve. I edited my answer to make my intentions more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the whole JSON structure, you don't need to use a wrapper. You can deserialize it to a generic json object, and also add new elements after that.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonObject();
obj.get("version"); // Version field
```