# Gson Polymorphic Serialization

Tags: java, gson

using Gson 2.2.2 I'm trying to serialize an array list of POJOs (Behaviors).

i have an adapter that's pretty much a copy of what i've seen online:

```
public class BehaviorAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Behavior> {

    private static final String CLASSNAME = "CLASSNAME";
    private static final String INSTANCE = "INSTANCE";

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Behavior src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {

        JsonObject retValue = new JsonObject();
        String className = src.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        retValue.addProperty(CLASSNAME, className);
        JsonElement elem = context.serialize(src);
        retValue.add(INSTANCE, elem);
        return retValue;
    }
}
```

The i register it like this:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();        
builder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Behavior.class, new BehaviorAdapter());
gson = builder.create();
```

Then when i try to serialize my ArrayList:

```
String json2 = gson.toJson(behaviors);
```

I get a stack overflow.

It appears that on line:

```
JsonElement elem = context.serialize(src);
```

It starts a recursive loop, going again and again through my serializer. So How do i register it so that this won't happen? I need to serialize the list and maintain polymorphism.

Comment: Ran into the serialization-recursion-issue in 2021 - and solved it using [`public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc);`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/gson-parent-2.8.7/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonSerializationContext.java#L48) with `Object.getClass()` as the second parameter instead of `src.getClass()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you found the infinite loop [the JsonSerializer docs warn about](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html#serialize-T-java.lang.reflect.Type-com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext-):

> However, you should never invoke it on the src object itself since that will cause an infinite loop (Gson will call your call-back method again).

The easiest way I can think of is to create a new Gson instance that does *not* have the handler installed, and run your instances through that.

As an end run, you could just serialize the `List<Behavior>` instead:

```
public class BehaviorListAdapter implements JsonSerializer<List<Behavior>> {

    private static final String CLASSNAME = "CLASSNAME";
    private static final String INSTANCE = "INSTANCE";

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(List<Behavior> src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
        for (Behavior behavior : src) {
            JsonObject behaviorJson = new JsonObject();
            String className = behavior.getClass().getCanonicalName();
            behaviorJson.addProperty(CLASSNAME, className);
            JsonElement elem = context.serialize(behavior);
            behaviorJson.add(INSTANCE, elem);
            array.add(behaviorJson);
        }
        return array;
    }
}

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
// use a TypeToken to make a Type instance for a parameterized type
builder.registerTypeAdapter(
    (new TypeToken<List<Behavior>>() {}).getType(),
    new BehaviorListAdapter());
gson = builder.create();
```

Comment: Thanks for the links! I looked there but not in the serialize function.

Comment: `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` seems to want a class, am i missing something?

Comment: No, sorry, that was me.  I meant [`registerTypeAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter(java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.Object)).

Comment: I'd also like to mention, since i lost a lot of time with this, when you serialize, you'll need to specify the typetoken. `Type typetoken = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Behavior>>() {}.getType();
gson.toJson(sprite.behaviors, typetoken);`

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java). The [test](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/test/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactoryTest.java) for that class has an example:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<BillingInstrument> rta = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(
    BillingInstrument.class)
    .registerSubtype(CreditCard.class);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(rta)
    .create();

CreditCard original = new CreditCard("Jesse", 234);
assertEquals("{\"type\":\"CreditCard\",\"cvv\":234,\"ownerName\":\"Jesse\"}",
    gson.toJson(original, BillingInstrument.class));
BillingInstrument deserialized = gson.fromJson(
    "{type:'CreditCard',cvv:234,ownerName:'Jesse'}", BillingInstrument.class);
assertEquals("Jesse", deserialized.ownerName);
assertTrue(deserialized instanceof CreditCard);
```

This class *isn't* in core Gson; you'll need to copy it into your project to use it.

Comment: This seems like a really good idea, except that i have a lot of subclasses.

Comment: For the RuntypeAdapterFactory to work when writing, I had to change "if (type.getRawType() != baseType) {
            return null;
 }" to if (!baseType.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            return null;
        } in the create method.

Comment: @Melanie: This is 100% necessary for Serialization to work. Cheers.

Comment: Can somebody explain how this example is used for multiple inheritances, like "CreditCard extends BillingInstruments", "BillingInstruments extends Instruments" and Instruments hold an enum-variable to distinguish what concrete type it is?

Answer (score 1):

I get what you are trying to do here, and i had the same issue.

I ended writing a simple abstract class

```
public abstract class TypedJsonizable extends Jsonizable {}
```

and registering a TypeHierarchyAdapter to my Gson instance

```
    protected static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter
    (TypedJsonizable.class,new TypedJsonizableSerializer());
```

The key for this TypeAdapter is not to invoke context.serialize and context.deserialize cause this would cause an infinite loop as stated from [Jeff Bowman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426891/jeff-bowman) in his answer, this TypeAdapter use reflection to avoid that.

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class TypedJsonizableSerializer implements JsonSerializer<TypedJsonizable>, JsonDeserializer<TypedJsonizable> {
static final String CLASSNAME_FIELD = "_className";
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TypedJsonizable.class);

@Override
public JsonElement serialize(TypedJsonizable src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject contentObj = new JsonObject();
    contentObj.addProperty(CLASSNAME_FIELD,src.getClass().getCanonicalName());

    for (Field field : src.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            if (field.get(src)!=null)
                contentObj.add(field.getName(),context.serialize(field.get(src)));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }
    return contentObj;
}

@Override
public TypedJsonizable deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    String className = jsonObject.get(CLASSNAME_FIELD).getAsString();
    if (className == null || className.isEmpty())
        throw new JsonParseException("Cannot find _className field. Probably this instance has not been serialized using Jsonizable jsonizer");
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Class<?> realClazz = (Class<?>) typeOfT;
        if (!realClazz.equals(clazz))
            throw new JsonParseException(String.format("Cannot serialize object of class %s to %s", clazz.getCanonicalName(),realClazz.getCanonicalName()));
        Object o  = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        for (Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (jsonObject.has(field.getName())) {
                field.set(o,context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(field.getName()) , field.getGenericType()));
            }
        }
        return (TypedJsonizable) o;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(String.format("Cannot find class with name %s . Maybe the class has been refactored or sender and receiver are not using the same jars",className));
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e){
        throw new JsonParseException(String.format("Cannot deserialize, got illegalAccessException %s ",e.getMessage()));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(String.format("Cannot deserialize object of class %s, unable to create a new instance invoking empty constructor",className));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution (workaround) for this issue: don't serialize base class in your class hierarchy but use descendants. For example:

```
...
protected static Gson gson;
...
GsonBuilder gsb = new GsonBuilder();
gsb.registerTypeAdapter(SomeBase.class, new MQPolymorphicSerializer<SomeBase>());
gson = gsb.create();
```

**SomeBase**:

```
public class SomeBase{
```

...
        }

**SomeDescendant**:

```
public class SomeDescendant extends SomeBase {
...
}
```

**Stack overflow exception case:**

```
gson.toJson(new SomeBase());
```

**Workaround case:**

```
gson.toJson(new SomeDescendant());
```

...and finally - serializer example:

```
public class MQPolymorphicSerializer<T> implements JsonSerializer<T>, JsonDeserializer<T> {
private static final String CLASSNAME = "CLASSNAME";
private static final String INSTANCE = "INSTANCE";

@Override
public JsonElement serialize(T src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject retValue = new JsonObject();
    String className = src.getClass().getName();
    retValue.addProperty(CLASSNAME, className);
    JsonElement elem = context.serialize(src);
    retValue.add(INSTANCE, elem);
    return retValue;
}

@Override
public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonPrimitive prim = (JsonPrimitive) jsonObject.get(CLASSNAME);
    String className = prim.getAsString();
    Class<?> klass = null;
    try {
        klass = Class.forName(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(INSTANCE), klass);
}
```

}