# Android gson AbstractAdapter.serialize is not called (polymorphic serialization)

Tags: android, json, serialization, polymorphism

Good day my fellow developers,

I'm struggling with gson lib from google in my Android app. I'm trying to serialize a list of objects to Json string, however without luck. My inheritance hierarchy looks like this:

```
interface IFloorPlanPrimitive
abstract class FloorPlanPrimitiveBase implements IFloorPlanPrimitive
class Wall extends FloorPlanPrimitiveBase 
class Mark extends FloorPlanPrimitiveBase
```

Pretty simple. There are some of fields in each class. I searched for the matter on the web and added this adapter class to facilitate with serializing/deserializing. Currently I'm unable to serialize, so let's focus on that.

```
public class FloorPlanPrimitiveAdapter implements
        JsonSerializer<FloorPlanPrimitiveBase>, JsonDeserializer<FloorPlanPrimitiveBase> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(FloorPlanPrimitiveBase src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
        result.add("type", new JsonPrimitive(src.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        result.add("properties", context.serialize(src, src.getClass()));

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public FloorPlanPrimitiveBase deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String type = jsonObject.get("type").getAsString();
        JsonElement element = jsonObject.get("properties");

        try {
            final String packageName = IFloorPlanPrimitive.class.getPackage().getName();
            return context.deserialize(element, Class.forName(packageName  + '.' + type));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Unknown element type: " + type, cnfe);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
public String getFloorPlanAsJSon() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBilder.registerTypeAdapter(FloorPlanPrimitiveBase.class, new FloorPlanPrimitiveAdapter());
    Gson gson = gsonBilder.create();

    List<IFloorPlanPrimitive> floorPlan = mRenderer.getFloorPlan();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(floorPlan);

    return jsonString;
}
```

From a simple debug I see that `serialize` method of `FloorPlanPrimitiveAdapter` is not being called when serializing and thus I don't get those "type" and "properties" fields in Json. Instead I get straight-forward Json string. I suppose this is due to mismatch in types. I'm asking to serialize `IFloorPlanPrimitive`, but instead pass `FloorPlanPrimitiveBase` which implements this interface. My expectation was that it should work :)

Can anyone point on how to deal with serialization and deserialization in this situation? How to overcome that "mismatch"?

Thank you in advance,

Kind regards, Greg.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

I want to share my solution to my own problem. I hope this will be helpful for others. Also, I would like to know if this solution has any flaws.

So, first the usage. I looked into another answer on SO (linked below). Also [this](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/712#issuecomment-183432959) issue on Gson github was also helpful (in particular I learnt there to pass a type parameter into `toJson()` method:

```
public String getFloorPlanAsJSon() {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

    final Type type = (new TypeToken<List<FloorPlanPrimitiveBase>>() {}).getType();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(type, new FloorPlanAdapter());
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    List<IFloorPlanPrimitive> floorPlan = mRenderer.getFloorPlan();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(floorPlan, type);

    return jsonString;
}
```

And now the `Adapter` I actually took from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244769/gson-polymorphic-serialization) SO answer (beware it has bug in it - the name of class put into Json is ArrayList instead of class of the element):

```
public class FloorPlanAdapter implements JsonSerializer<List<FloorPlanPrimitiveBase>> {

    private static final String CLASSNAME = "CLASSNAME";
    private static final String INSTANCE = "INSTANCE";

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(List<FloorPlanPrimitiveBase> src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                 JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray array = new JsonArray();

        for (FloorPlanPrimitiveBase primitiveBase : src) {
            JsonObject primitiveJson = new JsonObject();

            String className = primitiveBase.getClass().getCanonicalName();
            primitiveJson.addProperty(CLASSNAME, className);

            JsonElement elem = context.serialize(primitiveBase);
            primitiveJson.add(INSTANCE, elem);

            array.add(primitiveJson);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

As you can see it loops over all objects in `List<>` and processes it just like FloorPlanPrimitiveBaseAdapter in my original question.

This is how I deserialize it:

```
@Override
public List<FloorPlanPrimitiveBase> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    final String packageName = IFloorPlanPrimitive.class.getPackage().getName();
    List<FloorPlanPrimitiveBase> result = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();

    for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {
        final JsonObject asJsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
        String className = asJsonObject.get(CLASSNAME).getAsString();
        JsonElement serializedInstance = asJsonObject.get(INSTANCE);

        Class<?> klass;
        try {
            klass = Class.forName(packageName + '.' + className);
            final FloorPlanPrimitiveBase deserializedInstance = context.deserialize(serializedInstance, klass);
            result.add(deserializedInstance);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```