# How to convert polymorphic json string to java bean class

Tags: java, json, rest, javabeans, jackson

How can i map json to bean class with polymorphic  data type
i have three pattern of json statement

```
{
  actor:"ashok",
  verb:"completed"
}
```

or this

```
  {
      actor:["ashok","kumar"],
      verb:{
          disp:"en-us",
          url:{
             link:"url",
             tag:"tagname"
          }
      }
  }
```

or

```
{
      actor:{name:["ashok","kumar"],mail:["a@a.com","b@b.com"]}
      verb:{
          disp:"en-us",
          url:{
             link:"url",
             tag:"tagname"
          }
      }
  }
```

how can i map all these type of json in same bean class. i need a polymorphic bean class which can handle all type of objects of json and also able to handle single sting data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800433/polymorphism-with-gson

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Gson. it provide fromJson() method.