# Reading and writing JSON streams

Tags: java, json, sockets, gson

I am trying to read and write JSON directly to and from a socket stream using the `gson` library.

I have a base class that all messages are derived from:

```
abstract class MessageBase
{
    public String type = this.getClass().toString();
}
```

An example would be:

```
class RequestMessage extends MessageBase
{
    public String request = "my request";
}
```

What I wish to do is have the following methods:

```
MessageBase readMessage(Reader reader);
void writeMessage(Writer writer, MessageBase message);
```

Where they read and write directly from the stream.

This will allow me to call something like:

```
writeMessage(myWriter, (MessageBase) (new RequestMessage()))
```

or

```
MessageBase message = readMessage(myReader);

if (message instance of RequestMessage)
{
    RequestMessage request = (RequestMessage) message;

    // do something here
}
```

I hope it makes sense what I am hoping to achieve, is it even possible?

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sure its possible. What problems are you having with the implementation?

Comment: I don't have an implementation. Currently I send the JSON message down the pipe prefixed with the message length. Read the whole message into a string and deserialize using `Gson.fromJson()` but I need to know the type beforehand.

Comment: Well, Gson can already ready from streams directly (aka, you don't need to send the message length in the stream). And you can handle polymorphic serialization/deserialization with a type adapter. As described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800433/polymorphism-with-gson).

Comment: @Perception thank you that link helped me solve the problem. What is the protocol here. Perception has answered my question?

Comment: Perception should post his comment as an answer and you accept it.

Comment: @Ben - post your final solution as an answer, then accept it. So anybody who runs into this in the future can use it.