# How do I Gson-serialize an object extending a Collection?

Tags: java, gson

I have this class which I want to serialize:

```
class EnrichedList extends ArrayList<String> {
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

The out-of-the-box `Gson` serializer ignores the timestamp field because it's in a collection class. I know I can write a [TypeAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683689/507339) and manually handle the class, and it *might* be the solution I go for, but I want to explore my options. Are there any better option which scales and maintains better? Think of the scenario when a new developer enters the team and adds a field/property to the `EnrichedClass` without knowing he has to update the TypeAdapter simultaneously.

Evidence for my issue:

```
class EnrichedList extends ArrayList<String> {
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

class SimpleObject {
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
}


@Test
public void serializeIt() {
    EnrichedList list = new EnrichedList();
    list.add("Fred");
    list.add("Flintstone");
    System.out.println("Enriched list: " + new Gson().toJson(list));
    System.out.println("Simple object: " + new Gson().toJson(new SimpleObject()));
}
```

Produces this output:

```
Enriched list: ["Fred","Flintstone"]
Simple object: {"timestamp":1418739904470}
```

Desired output (example):

```
Enriched list: {"timestamp":1418739904470, "list": ["Fred","Flintstone"]}
Simple object: {"timestamp":1418739904470}
```

Comment: The JSON you want is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So given your edit, with corrected JSON of

```
{"timestamp":1418739904470, "list": ["Fred","Flintstone"]}
```

you have to ask yourself where the key `list` comes from. What if your collection was a `Set`? What if it was something else? Gson doesn't have such defaults.

The most appropriate solution, in my opinion, is to use composition over inheritance (obviously, only if that's possible).

```
class EnrichedList {
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Gson will have no trouble serializing that to the JSON you want.