# Android - Inheritance and abstract classes in GSon + RetroFit

Tags: android, gson, abstract-class, retrofit

I have the following class hierarchy

```
public abstract class SyncModel {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Long globalId;

    @Expose
    protected DateTime lastModified;
    
    /* Constructor, methods... */
}

public class Event extends SyncModel {
    @Expose
    private String title;
    
    /* Other fields, constructor, methods... */
}
```

I need to send an Event instance to backend.

#### Case 1. `@Body`

When I post the Event instance in a request body, it is serialized fine.

RetroFit Java interface:

```
public interface EventAPI {
    @POST("/event/create")
    void sendEvent(@Body Event event, Callback<Long> cbEventId);
}
```

RetroFit log:

```
D   Retrofit    ---> HTTP POST http://hostname:8080/event/create
D   Retrofit    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D   Retrofit    Content-Length: 297
D   Retrofit    {"title":"Test Event 01",...,"id":null,"lastModified":"2015-07-09T14:17:08.860+03:00"}
D   Retrofit    ---> END HTTP (297-byte body)
```

#### Case 2. `@Field`

But when I post the Event instance in a request parameter, only abstract class is serialized.

RetroFit Java interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/event/create")
void sendEvent(@Field("event") Event event, Callback<Long> cbEventId);
```

RetroFit log:

```
D   Retrofit    ---> HTTP POST http://hostname:8080/event/create
D   Retrofit    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
D   Retrofit    Content-Length: 101
D   Retrofit    event=SyncModel%28globalId%3Dnull%2C+lastModified%3D2015-07-09T13%3A36%3A33.510%2B03%3A00%29
D   Retrofit    ---> END HTTP (101-byte body)
```

Notice the difference.

#### Questions

Why?
How can I send a serialized Event instance to backend in a request parameter?
Do I need to write a custom JSON serializer for abstract class? (example: [Polymorphism with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800433/polymorphism-with-gson))
Or is it a RetroFit specific feature (to ignore child classes)?

I've also noticed that in the 2nd case `globalId` field serialized name is `globalId`, but it should be `id`! It makes me think that RetroFit uses a different `GsonConverter` for `@Field` than for `@Body` parameters...

---

#### Configuration

Gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.+'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.+'
compile ('com.fatboyindustrial.gson-jodatime-serialisers:gson-jodatime-serialisers:1.1.0') {  // GSON + Joda DateTime
    exclude group: 'joda-time', module: 'joda-time'
}
```

REST client

```
public final class RESTClient {

    // Not a real server URL
    public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://hostname:8080";

    // one-time initialization
    private static GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder()
            .serializeNulls()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'");
    // Joda DateTime type support
    private static Gson gson = Converters.registerDateTime(builder).create();

    private static RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)     // for development
            .setEndpoint(SERVER_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))    // custom converter
            .build();

    private static final EventAPI eventService = restAdapter.create(EventAPI.class);
    /* + Getter for eventService */

    static {
        // forget them
        restAdapter = null;
        gson = null;
        builder = null;
    }

}
```

Call

```
RESTClient.getEventService().sendEvent(event, new Callback<Long>() {/* ... */});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`@Field`'s documentation](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/version-one/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/http/Field.java). It says:

> Values are converted to strings using `String#valueOf(Object)` and then form URL encoded.

`String#valueOf(Object)` makes a call to `Object#toString()` inside. I suppose your `SyncModel` has a `toString()` method and `Event` does not. When Retrofit calls `String.valueOf(event)`, `SyncModel#toString()` is called instead of `Event#toString()`. That's why you don't see `title` in the Retrofit logs.

Gson doesn't play any role at all when converting `@Field` parameters. It can be though - you can make your `toString()` method look something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return GsonProvider.getInstance().toJson(this);
}
```

Put this inside your abstract `SyncModel` class and it should work for `Event` as well.

Comment: To add to this, it makes a lot of sense given that you would likely not be sending complex objects as query parameters, but would be sending them as part of the request body instead.

Comment: Nice guess! I'll check it and accept the answer asap.